# Git Pull via REST in Lucee

Tags: cfml, lucee

Attempting to create a REST service in Lucee to pull down changes in the git repo.

Server is Lucee on Tomcat on Windows Server 2012

```
<cffunction name="gitPull"
    access = "remote"
    httpMethod="GET"
    restPath="git/pull"
>
    <cftry>
        <cfexecute 
            name="C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cmd.exe" 
            arguments="/c c:\sites\git-pull-stadge.bat" 
            variable="batchOutput" 
            <!--- outputfile="c:\sites\stadge-pull-output.txt" --->
            timeout="5000"
            errorVariable="errorMessage"
            >
            Lucee documentation says this tag must have a body
        </cfexecute>

    <cfcatch>
        <cfscript>
            return cfcatch;
        </cfscript>
    </cfcatch>
    </cftry>

    <cfscript>
        return {'output' = batchOutput, 'errors' = errorMessage};
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```

Batch file is as follows:

```
c:
cd \repo_folder
git config --global credential.helper wincred
git fetch
git pull
```

The Lucee service is Log On As Local System

Batch file works when called from any folder on the server, but the batch file is not run and no output is returned by the function.
Introducing errors into the syntax successfully triggers the cftry/cfcatch and the error is returned as it should be.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I did. The solution was several iterations of trial/error.  I'll be applying this to another project in the next month and will post the solution when it's a little more polished.

Comment: Sounds good. That, or a brief summary of what the issue was, would be great.